# Designing page in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've installed Visual Studio Professional 2010 [without any error] but I can not design webpage in it. I've installed

- VB.NET
- C#
- Web Development [or something like that] only.

I can code, debug in VB.NET / C# but the problem is with designing page !
[image: VS 2010 Screenshot]

The "Design View" option is missing in the ASPX file.

System info: Windows 7 X64 Ultimate [uninstalled SP1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved

**Tools->Options->HTML Designer->Check the box in front of [Enable HTML Designer]**

[image: Enable HTML]

Answer (score 1):

You are viewing `"Default.aspx.cs"` which is a code behind page which can't be viewed in design mode.

So just change your control to `"Default.aspx"` and press `Design` button as shown below.

[image: Design mode]

Or press <kbd>F7</kbd> key from  `"Default.aspx.cs"` page where you will see the design mode.

Comment: Nothing happens after I press F7, the "Design mode" option is not there. I can see the HTML lookup, the CS code, and CS [Design mode]. But no graphical designer mode for the ASPX file

Comment: But thnx for the response bro (: